# right side menu need to move bottom

Tags: html, css, menu, slide

I have a menu with 5 items and currently it is placed on right side of the screen with hover slide but I need the bottom of the page (fixed in footer) with hover to slide up and there is top arrow icon with menu text, I need this icon position reverse when menu slide open, thanks in advance

```css
.menu {
  font-weight: 100;
  background: #ffc20e;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -3px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: -3px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  right: -130px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  color: #222;
}
.menu:hover, .menu:focus {
  transform: translate3d(-130px, 0, 0);
  animation-timing-function: 1s ease-in;
}
.menu .title {
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  left: 10px;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.menu .nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-weight: 100;
}
.menu .nav li {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.menu .nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
}
.menu .nav li a:hover {
  color: #aaa;
}
.arrow{
    width: 15px;
    margin-right: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <div class="title"><img src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1883/PNG/512/caretsymbol_120671.png" class="arrow">MENU</div>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that ?

```css
.menu {
  font-weight: 100;
  background: #ffc20e;
  width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -3px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: -3px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  bottom: -90px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  color: #222;
}
.menu:hover, .menu:focus {
  transform: translate(0px, -90px);
  animation-timing-function: 1s ease-in;
}
.menu:hover img, .menu:focus img{
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  // or transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.menu .title {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: 10px;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.menu .nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-weight: 100;
}
.menu .nav li {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 30px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.menu .nav li a {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
}
.menu .nav li a:hover {
  color: #aaa;
}
.arrow{
    width: 15px;
    margin-right: 7px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="title"><img src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1883/PNG/512/caretsymbol_120671.png" class="arrow">MENU</div>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and given your prompt time much appreciated! Yes this is what I want, can you suggest for arrow icon reverse when menu slide up

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).